# Div focus only works when tabbed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following `Modal` component. Upon a button click, I open the modal.

I can then close Modal with a close button. When the modal closes, I wan to `focus` on another div element.

This works fine as long as I tab to the close button and press enter or space or left mouse click.

But if I don't tab to close button. And instead only mouse click to close modal, the focus does not land on the div.

Is this expected behaviour? I am trying to land focus on the div even when mouse clicked without tabbing.

This is the modal.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Modal(props) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const btnRef = props.btnRef;

  const openModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
    btnRef.current.focus(); // the focus logic
  };

  const handleModalClick = (e) => {
    if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
      closeModal();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button id='open-btn' onClick={openModal}>Open Modal</button>
      {isOpen && (
        <div
          style={{ backgroundColor: "greenyellow", padding: 10, margin: 10 }}
          className="modal" onClick={handleModalClick}>
          <div className="modal-content">
            <h2>{props.title}</h2>
            <p>{props.content}</p>
            <button id='close-btn' onClick={closeModal}>Close Modal</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Modal;
```

This is how I am calling the Modal.

Also where the div on which I wish to focus on is located.

```
import {useRef} from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Modal from "./Modal.jsx";

const App = () => {
  const btnRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <div id='modal'>
          <Modal
            title="Example Modal"
            content="This is some example content for the modal."
            btnRef={btnRef}
          />
        </div>

        {/* This is the div where the focus should land after modal closes */}
        <div
          id='focus-div'
          ref={btnRef}
          tabIndex='0'
          onClick={() => alert('something')}
          style={{ padding: 20, backgroundColor: "yellow", cursor: 'pointer' }}
        >
          {'name'}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default App
```

Comment: Is it a bootstrap modal?

Comment: @aldwinp35 No just a simple modal. Not using any libs. The Modal implementation is above.

Comment: @kar I'm not quite sure if I understand it correctly, but you perhaps want to have an `useEffect` call with a dependency `[btnRef]` and inside there call `btnRef.current.focus();`?

Comment: Your code is fine. I tested in codesanbox. Just add style to the focus. 
```#focus-div:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: @aldwinp35 Try to click close modal without tabbing to the close button. It doesn't focus on the div.

Comment: Check it in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-sunset-hx1w6l?file=/src/App.js.